# Joomla: Add a page class depending on user group

Tags: joomla, usergroups

Joomla 2.5
Is there a way to add a specific css class to the body which is specific to a logged in user's group.

For example I have four user groups, Individual Premium, Individual Standard, Corporate Premium and Corporate Standard. I want to have something like:

```
<body class="individual-standard">
```

or

```
<body class="corporate-standard">
```

This is the current body tag:

```
<body id="ff-<?php echo $fontfamily; ?>" class="<?php echo $fontstyle; ?> <?php echo $pstyle; ?> <?php echo $bgstyle; ?> <?php echo $pageclass; ?> iehandle">
```

I have tried putting this in the head:

```
 $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $pageclass ="";
    if(array_key_exists('individual premium',$user->groups)){
    $pageclass .="individual-premium";
    }
    if(array_key_exists('corporate premium',$user->groups)){
    $pageclass .="corporate-premium";
    }
     if(array_key_exists('corporate standard',$user->groups)){
    $pageclass .="corporate-standard";
    }
     if(array_key_exists('individual standard',$user->groups)){
    $pageclass .="individual-standard";
    }
```

And this is the body tag:

```
<body id="ff-<?php echo $fontfamily; ?>" class="<?php echo $fontstyle; ?>  <?php echo $pstyle; ?> <?php echo $bgstyle; ?> <?php echo $pageclass; ?> iehandle">
```

Answer (score 1):

You first get the user groups and than set the class as per below code-

In index.php of template folder

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $pageclass ="";
    if(array_key_exists('individual premium',$user->groups)){
    $pageclass .="individual-premium";
    }
    if(array_key_exists('corporate premium',$user->groups)){
    $pageclass .=" corporate-premium";
    }
     if(array_key_exists('corporate standard',$user->groups)){
    $pageclass .=" corporate-standard";
    }
     if(array_key_exists('individual standard',$user->groups)){
    $pageclass .=" individual-standard";
    }

       <body id="ff-<?php echo $fontfamily; ?>" class="<?php echo $fontstyle; ?>  <?php echo $pstyle; ?> <?php echo $bgstyle; ?> <?php echo $pageclass; ?> iehandle">
```

for example if a user in "corporate premium" and "corporate standard" group
page class will be-  `corporate-premium corporate-standard`

Comment: Thanks @Irfan. I have just updated my question. I needed to add two extra usergroups. I tried your original code, but I was unsure of how to work <body <?php echo $class?>> into my current body tag. I keep getting something like this: <body id="ff-helvetica" class="f-default class='' style2 simple my-profile iehandle">

Comment: @user1670411:I have update the code.If it does not but than, would be great if  you can post your full code,How did you apply my code in your?

Comment: Sorry, but that is still not working. I tried the code exactly as you have it.

Comment: @user1670411:ok,Could you plese give me the output of $groups=& JFactory::getUser()->groups;print_r($groups) And also what is the output after update;

Comment: sorry I am limited in my PHP knowledge. How do I give you the output?

Comment: @Irfan please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914758/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Thinking to "hide" fields, where the "lower" User Groups will hide more and the "higher" will hide less (the highest nothing), it would be better to have it "exclusive" in a pyramidal way, something like:

```
<?php $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $pageclass ="";
    if(array_key_exists('Reg-D group ID',$user->groups)){
    $pageclass .="reg-d";
    } else if(array_key_exists('Reg-C group ID',$user->groups)){
         $pageclass .=" reg-c";
         } else if(array_key_exists('Reg-B group ID',$user->groups)){
              $pageclass .=" reg-b";
              } else if(array_key_exists('Reg-A group ID',$user->groups)){
                   $pageclass .=" reg-a";
                   }
?>
```

Where $user->groups variable returns the User Group ID, [here an alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10475176/12970100)

I'm not sure about the code, What do you think about ?

Comment: A tip on coding standards: `else if` as two words is a violation of the PSR-12 standards -- you should be writing `elseif` as one word.  Since your condition block is using `elseif` statements, there will only be one string appended; for this reason, I recommend a lookup array that will allow for a much more concise translation of data -- this will be much easier to read and maintain too.

Comment: So the lookup & translation can look like this: https://3v4l.org/092H6  Also, I'd like to mention another PSR-12 violation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914758/2943403