# How to change a Joomla User Group with php

Tags: php, joomla2.5

In a Joomla 2.5 site I want to assign a registered user to another group after they complete a form.  The user would be logged in when they complete the form which will be created in Fabrik so that I can add a PHP script to run on save.  My php skills are rudimentary.  What would the lines in php look like that adds the current user to a group?

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Changing_user_groups and also check this http://docs.joomla.org/Custom_user_groups

Answer (score 4):

You can use [JUserHelper::setUserGroups](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/User/JUserHelper.html#setUserGroups) to set the group(s) of a user.

To retrieve the current user you can use [JFactory::getUser](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/JFactory.html#getUser).

When you have the user, you can (I haven't confirmed this) probably [get the id](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/User/JUser.html#$id) right away. Some non-tested code which will hopefully get you on the way:

```
 $user = JFactory::getUser();
 $userId = $user->id;
 JUserHelper::setUserGroups($userId, 3);
```

Or in short:

```
 JUserHelper::setUserGroups(JFactory::getUser()->id, 3); // 3 Is the group number
```

You can find the group ID's by going into the `table-prefix_usergroups` table and retrieve the primary key. I haven't found a way to retrieve a list of groups without going into the database, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13325261/1271566) may help.

A screenshot of my (non-edited) database with usergroups:

[image: Usergroups joomla 2.5]

Comment: please note this appears to throw SQL errors if used in Joomla 3.x

Answer (score 2):

Here I used a different approach as JUserHelper::setUserGroups method always failed with my Joomla 3.3.1 installation.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();//get current user
$g = array('2'=>2,'3'=>3);//2 for registered user, 3 for author
$user->groups = $g;
$user->save();
```

Comment: this also worked well for me (J!3.3.x), and abstracts away from using direct database commands

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Joomla 3.7.5, and this method worked for me:

```
JUserHelper::setUserGroups($joomlaId, array(10));
```

Where, $joomlaId is the id of the user I want to change.  This sets the user to only be a member of group 10, and saves the changes to the user DB immediately.

Comment: I confirm that it works with the latest Joomla 3.x version. You can assign a user to multiple groups, inserting their number in the array. The ids of the groups can be seens in the backend, without the need to access the db.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at the **addUserToGroup** method (since Joomla Platform 11.1)

```
JUserHelper::addUserToGroup (JFactory::getUser()->id, 3); // 3 Is the group number
```

So for example if your user was previously in the 'registered' group (id=2), he/she will also be assigned to group 3 after this.

Similarly there is also the **removeUserFromGroup** method which does the opposite.

As per the documentation, it may be useful to note that the **setUserGroups** method supports an array for the groups, whereas the other 2 methods I mention here support an integer.

> setUserGroups(integer $userId, array $groups) : boolean
>
> addUserToGroup(integer $userId, integer $groupId) : boolean
>
> removeUserFromGroup(integer $userId, integer $groupId) : boolean

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JUserHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any useful way to do this in joomla 3, so here's a quickie for people who just need this to work:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("replace into xo6uf_user_usergroup_map values ($user_id, $group_id)");
$db->query();
```