# add different body CLASS based on if a user group is signed in Joomla

Tags: joomla, head, usergroups

I have this

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$pageclass ="";
if(array_key_exists('Basic Spinervals Cycling Membership',$user->groups)) {
  $pageclass .="basicMemberUsers";
}
if(array_key_exists('Download Club',$user->groups)) {
  $pageclass .=" downloadClubUsers";
}
if(array_key_exists('   DVD of the Month Club',$user->groups)) {
  $pageclass .=" MonthClubUsers";
}
if(array_key_exists('Registered',$user->groups)) {
  $pageclass .=" RegisteredUsers";
}
```

In my head tag in my index.php

then I replaced body tag with this

```
<body class="<?php echo $this['config']->get('body_classes'); ?>">
```

but not working.

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting a blank page? The wrong class? which wrong class? You need to give enough information to get help. "It's not working" is not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

`$user->groups` variable returns the ID of the usergroup, not the usergroup name. you could take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13325261/4086739